# Smart App Banner not showing for my application when application is not installed

Tags: html, ios, iphone, smartbanner

I'm using the meta tag for displaying my application ios in the app banner for iphone/ipad devices.

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=xxxxxxx"/>
```

when I do tests using an Iphone, the banner worked very will if the application is installed, if it's not installed the banner is not showing.

I do also the same test with others applications like facebook and others, the banner works fine in all cases.

What can be the problem ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From http://www.raywenderlich.com/80347/smart-app-banners-tutorial:

> Users can easily dismiss a Smart App Banner by tapping the X button
>   on the left. Once dismissed, it doesn’t show itself again for that
>   user on that website, even if the website is reloaded. The only way to
>   get it to show again is if the user clears some metadata on that iOS
>   device.

Comment: Thank you Nabil, that's really what I'm looking for

Comment: In the Settings app, go to Safari -> Advanced -> Website Data and remove the website's data you want to refresh.

Comment: I've had to do a settings reset by going to  `Settings > General > Reset > Reset All Settings` for it work.. clearing the website settings didn't work for me

Comment: Edit: I had to do both clearing of website settings AND "Reset all settings"